# How to simplify the following assertion?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have started learning discrete mathematics and I came across this exercise problem in the book "Verification of sequential and concurrent programs".

Simplify the following assertion:
∃x: (x < t ∧ (p ∧ (q ∧ r))) ∨ s =u

Other than applying the distributive law, which gives (p ∧ q) ∧ (p ∧ r), 
and (t ∧ p ∧ q) ∧ (t ∧ p ∧ r), how can I proceed with the simplification?

Comment: $(x < t)$ is a formula and thus you cannot conflate the *term* $t$ with the sentenrial variables like $p,q,r$.

Comment: Same for the formula $(s=u)$.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for clarifying. So, ∃x: (x < t ∧ ((p ∧ q) ∧ (p ∧ r))) ∨ s =u, how do I proceed after this? Or, is that the extent to which I can simplify?

Comment: Maybe use some of the abbreviations of page 40, like e.g. $∃x < t : (p ∧ q ∧ r) ∨ s =u$...

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I will try that and let you know.